# Regex to validate middle name (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a Dutch '[middlename](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tussenvoegsel)' using javascript regex.
This is a really complex one, because each group depends on the previous group.

- there is a maximum of 3 groups
- when there is just 1 group the first letter have to be uppercased
- when there are 3 groups the first & last group should be uppercased, the second group should start with a lowercased character.

Here are some valid middle names.

> - Velde
> - van der Velde
> - van der Heide
> - de Groot
> - de Jong
> - Jansen
> - Maarsen
> - van de Berg

Here are some invalid names.

> - Van de berg
> - Van de Berg
> - De Jong
> - velde

Comment: Thus, what have you tried ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you, can you show us what have you tried? [Check the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: It would be nice if you provide some invalid names too.

Comment: _in de Grot_ _van de Berg_ == _when there are 3 groups the first & last group should be uppercased_ ???

Comment: As i understood your question, this /([A-Z][a-z]+)|[a-z]+\s([A-Z][a-z]+)|[a-z]+\s[a-z]+\s([A-Z][a-z]+)/ should help you. Can you tell what is the middle name in van de Velde, Velde and de Groot???

Comment: @JyotiradityaParmar You are awesome, this seems to work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will work for what you're asking:

```
/^[a-z]*\s?[a-z]*\s?[A-Z][a-z]+$/
```

JSFiddle with some examples: https://jsfiddle.net/amst7c29/

Comment: This is really awesome, this does work indeed, thanks!